# AutoSearchTextView dropdown flickers when data changes

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-filter

I have an AutoSearchTextView in the actionbar.  When I filter the data the dropdown hides and then shows very quickly.  I really would prefer the effect on the play store, where you filter results, the dropdown is always visible but the content in the dropdown changes.

This is my filter code in my Adapter, run history query, gets the history and sets the list items.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                ResortFilterResult result = new ResortFilterResult();
                String substr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (constraint.length() > 0) {
                        result.setHistory(runHistoryQuery(substr));
                    }
                    if (constraint.length() >= 3) {
                        LCResort[] resorts = searchResortWithQuery(substr);
                        result.setQueryResults(Arrays.asList(resorts));
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = result;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                ResortFilterResult result = (ResortFilterResult)results.values;
                history = result.getHistory();
                resorts = result.getQueryResults();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
    }
    return filter;
}
```

EDIT: I am one step closer - It turns out dismiss dropdown on the TextView is being called every time I type a new character!

Comment: If you're going to extend the filter, do it the right way. Don't set the results from the `runHistoryQuery()` method(I'm surprised you didn't get in troubles), instead make it return the new data and assign it to the `FilterResults` object(along with the count). In the `publishResults()` callback don't just blindly call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, assign the newly received data(from  the FilterResults parameter) and then call the method.

Comment: "don't just blindly call notifyDataSetChanged()" Not sure what you mean, the data has been changed, so thats the appropriate place.  I agree that the data should be set in publish results - was doing things a bit of a weird way before.  But the order should still be set data, notifyDataSetChanged surely?

Comment: Set data, call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. If you change the data in `performFiltering()` you're changing it from a background thread and there is the possibility that the `ListView` will see those changes before you get in the `publishResults()`(which runs on the main UI thread) to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: why not to use a FilterQueryProvider?  no need to play with custom Adapters,  Filters etc,

Comment: @Luksprog Thank's gotcha, copied code from elsewhere and just checked the docs...thats for the heads up.  This doesn't stop the flickering though. :(

Comment: @pskink What i'm doing is more complex than the question - I don't need cursors and I need a custom adatper, it's not much more code.

Comment: just use a SimpleCursorAdapter,  really,  no need for any custom Adapter and it has built in FilterQueryProvider

Comment: @pskink - You're not reading

Comment: Are you manually showing the drop down or are you doing anything special with the widget?

Comment: Edited code to reflect current version - I am manually showing the dropdown when the search bar is focused, so that I can show search history instantly. In order to do this I have using a custom widget which performs filtering if the textview is focused. I had forgotten about this...could well be the issue in there somewhere.

Comment: Commented out overriden methods in custom view so its basically just a AutoCompleteTextView but did not make a difference

Comment: @pskink As I've said to you before, please don't use comments as a discussion forum, if you have an answer please use the section with your reasoning. As always I appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Okay, It turns out the answer was quite simple, sometimes the best way it to just check the source code :)

AutoSearchTextView has a method `public void onFilterComplete(int count)` which in turn calls 
`private void updateDropDownForFilter(int count)`, if the count is zero the dropdown will be hidden.

You **must** set count on your FilterResults object returned from your Filter `protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)`  method.

```
filterResults.count = result.getHistory().size() + result.getQueryResults().size();
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

please don't reinvent the wheel, use existing **Filter** instead of creating your own one

and the easiest is to use **FilterQueryProvider** together with e.g. **SimpleCursorAdapter** or when extending **CursorAdapter** just override *runQueryOnBackgroundThread*(), using that you will avoid errors like you have now

EDIT:

in your case if you dont need a custom Adapter use a **SimpleCursorAdapter** with custom **FilterQueryProvider** overriding *runQuery*() you can return all the data you need (see my answer here how i query wikipedia: [How to dynamically add suggestions to autocompletetextview with preserving character status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara)), if you **REALLY** need a custom Adapter extend **CursorAdapter** and do exactly the same in *runQueryOnBackgroundThread*() what you did in **FilterQueryProvider**.*runQuery*(), also when your data comes from more then one source use a **MergeCursor** but its perfectly ok to just use one **MatrixCursor**

Comment: Hi as you can see I have found a solution.  Please show code to demonstrate how your answer solves the problem.  How exactly is my code re-inventing the wheel a Filter does not exist to filter data as I need

Comment: you reinvent the wheel since you are extending the Filter dealing with FilterResults and its implementation details like values, count, also you have to integrate your custom Filter with your custom Adapter, all of it is already done in CorsorAdapter: all you need is to perform search query,  that's it

Comment: AutoSearchTextView adapter must implement filterable, as I said I don't need a cursor adapter it doesn't make sense for my data type which doesn't need cursors. If you have an answer post code that shows how I can have an AutoSearchTextView which does two requests - 1 to the web and one to the search history content provider and then displays this content. If you don't explain how to achieve this, I can't make you as correct answer.

Comment: I would argue that produces more fragile code, why should I convert my java objects into cursors just for the sake of using a cursor adapter, it feels like pushing a round peg into a square hole.  Merging cursors can be prone to problems especially if the data aren't quite the same.  In reality overriding a filter is exactly the same amount of code as overriding runQueryonBackgroundThread. It seems like an academic point you are trying to make and SO isn't the place, you can't tell me why my code is wrong and answer the original question, the code works, it doesn't seem to be bad practice